# Looking up a value in Row of another Sheet

Tags: arrays, vba, matching

I am trying to create an open ended test with `VBA`. I have placed various permutations of answers in a second sheet and used something like this:

```
Sub Q1()
If (Sheet1.Cells(4, 2) = Sheet2.Cells(4, 3)) Or (Sheet1.Cells(4, 2) = Sheet2.Cells(4, 4)) Or (Sheet1.Cells(4, 2) = Sheet2.Cells(4, 5)) Then

Sheet1.Cells(4, 4) = 1

Else

Sheet1.Cells(4, 4) = 0

End If

End Sub
```

That works just fine. I have some answers that have 120 different correct permutations that I put into a single row (each permutation takes up its own cell on that row)

My goal is to have a `Sheet1` cell's input compared against the row. If there is a match, the output will be the same as above and the same goes for no match. How can I make my row into an array then search for the `sheet1` cell's value?

Thanks!

Comment: You can loop through the Values of Of that Row, or you can just find the value in that Row, or you can read that row in an Array and loop through the array and find your value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this will work: Change the values as per your requirement.

```
Sub Q1()

Dim i As Integer

For i = 1 To 120 ' Loop running from 1st column to 120th Column of row 4. Change if values are n other row or columns

    If Sheet1.Cells(4, 2) = Sheet2.Cells(4, i) Then

        Sheet1.Cells(4, 4) = 1
        Exit For
    Else

        Sheet1.Cells(4, 4) = 0

    End If

Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Mikku you are the bomb. I didn't even think to loop like that. THANK YOU :D

Comment: @DanielFlandersThedanflan .. Happy to Help :)

Comment: I have a random follow up question. If I was to account for user input variations (like spaces and additional punctuation (the answers for this test are IP addresses)) would I be better off formatting all input or something else? Thanks again

Comment: @DanielFlandersThedanflan .. I would suggest to use Clean Trim, check if the Value of the cell contains anything other than Numbers and Dots. That will do the Job. This [link](http://eforexcel.com/wp/vba-function-to-validate-ip-addresss/) might help